# Add square brackets at beginning and end of log files used by Python logging module

Tags: python, logging

even if the Python logging module offers a way to format each message, since I want to obtain a JSON file structure, it should look like this:

```
[
{...},
{...}
]
```

There are 2 main things I'm not able to set using Python logging module:

- the square brackets
- using the comma (,) for each line except for the last one right before the closing square bracket.

How to easily solve this problem?

Comment: How would you know when the last line was written to place the closing bracket?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I was wondering if the logging module could offer the possibility to write messages in a sort of file template or similar, to accomplish this task or be exported as JSON file in the right way

Comment: Maybe this is why no sane person writes logs in JSON? Maybe JSON Lines but not JSON.

Comment: The Python module "cutelog" is able to only read JSON files. Did not ask if people who wrote it were sane or not, sorry.